# WebGL build project not open

Tags: unity, unity-webgl

I am a beginner in unity. Every time I build a project in WebGL this message shows up when I try to run it, "Failed to download file Build/build projectb.data. Loading web pages via a file:// URL without a web server is not supported by this browser. Please use a local development web server to host Unity content, or use the Unity Build and Run option". I want to upload it on learn unity but cant because of this.

Comment: What exact steps are you taking when you try to run the game? Did you click "Build and Run" as the error message suggests, instead of just "Build" and then opening the HTML page? "Build and Run" launches a local program to act as a web server for serving the files your game relies on in a way that passes muster for your browser's security protections. Without that server running (ie. just trying to open the HTML file on its own), your browser will block the JavaScript code from doing some of the things your game needs it to do.

Comment: i clicked on build as i want to upload it on unity learn as a webgl link but unity learn wont accept it because of the error. but when i click on "build and run" it works

Comment: If that solved your problem, want to post your solution as an Answer below?

Comment: no its still not working when i try to run it using it's HTML file in its build folder.

Comment: As I explained above, a WebGL game *cannot* work when you just open the file in its build folder. The permissions model used by WebGL depends on a webserver hosting the files.

Comment: ok i understand now Thanks for the help